# android studio error builder (android.content.context) in builder cannot be applied to (anonymous.android.view.view.onclicklistener)

Tags: java, android-studio

I cant do anything because of the error 'builder (android.content.context) in builder cannot be applied to (anonymous.android.view.view.onclicklistener)' in MainActivity.java. pls help.

```
package com.ahotbrew.admobinterstitial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.*;

import com.ahotbrew.admobinterstitial.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
Button mPlayButton;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPlayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

    mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {

            }

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {


        }
    });

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

}

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content
shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("Game.html"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

});
    }}
```

the error is on the word **this** in the line:

> client = new
>   GoogleApiClient.Builder(**this**).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgcfW.png)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you find the solution ?